# Is there an equation for factoring an quadratic equation.

Tags: factoring, quadratics

Firstly, the title may be a little hard to understand so could someone please suggest a better one and make up for my 'ignorance.'

Onto the question. If I have a quadratic equation:
$$ax^2+bx+c$$
Is there a way for me to factor this to $(nx+r)(tx+s)$ by just using an equation. For example say I have the equation:
$$2x^2+x-6$$
Can I factor this to $(2x-3)(x+2)$ only using an equation not the traditional method of look, guess, test : if right stop, if wrong repeat.

The reason I ask this is because I have made a formula to do what I have described and I am not sure if any mathematicians have done this before. I want to know if I have made a discovery or rediscovered something already found.

The formula is 
$d$ = quadratic formula,
$ax^2+bx+c = (x-d)*(x -(ad+b))$

Comment: See my answer as a plain example so that you can do more of those, the other answers provided are more formal (and mathematically arguably better).

Comment: Always check for factors of the intercept coefficent ($c$) if an equation does factor easily you will find that they form the majority of the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Given the quadratic polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$, with $a\neq 0$, by using the quadratic formula you can find its roots, lets say $$r_1=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\quad\text{and}\quad r_2=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

So the polynomial can be factorised as
$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-r_1)(x-r_2).$$

Answer (score 1):

This is well known.

It is called the quadratic formula.

The roots of
$ax^2+bx+c$
are
$\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{d}}{2a}
$
where
$d = b^2-4ac$.

If $d > 0$,
there are two real roots.

If $d < 0$
there are two complex roots.

If $d = 0$
there is one repeated root.

Comment: I am well aware of the quadratic formula. I am not finding roots. I am factoring the equation. On a quadratic when a>1 you are no longer factoring, you are finding roots.

Comment: As Mario G stated, finding the roots is equivalent to factoring. Let's see your formula. I will be very surprised if it is new.

Comment: d = quadratic formula, sgn(x) = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function, so ax^2+bx+c = (x-sgn(d)d)*(x - sgn(a(d)+b)(ad+b))

Comment: sorry ignore the sgn() function I wasn't following my work for a second. ax^2+bx+c = (x-d)*(x -(ad+b))

Comment: Factoring and finding the roots is the exact same thing. A polynomial is *reducible*, that means it can be factored further, if it has at least one root. Thus, finding roots is how you factor a polynomial.

Comment: +1 for the only answer to explicitly consider roots being complex

Answer (score 1):

Given a quadratic $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, it is a bit ambiguous what you mean by $d = quadratic formula$.

$$d=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

The quadratic gives two roots, so rewrite your equation to be more accurate. Perhaps call them $d_1$ and $d_2$ in accordance with the $\pm$ that appears in the quadratic formula. Now let's consider your formula.

$$(x-d)(x -(ad+b))$$
$$ = x^2 -dx -(ad+b)x +d(ad+b)$$
$$ = x^2 -(d + ad+b)x +d(ad+b)$$

Regardless of the ambiguity of $d$, this is not giving us the $a$ coefficient for the quadratic term. If you correct your equation, it'll likely match the following procedure:

Use the quadratic equation to find each root, make the linear factors, and multiply the two factors by $a$.

$$f(x)=a(x-d_1)(x-d_2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: Factor $x^2+8x+2$ It is not nicely factorable. So use the quadratic formula to find solutions to $x^2+8x+2=0$ Verify that the solutions are $x=-4 \pm \sqrt14$ So working backwards, the factors came from $(x+4+\sqrt14)(x+4-\sqrt14)$. It is maybe not the cleanest way of doing, but it works...

Comment: The area this starts to fall apart at is when a>1. When you use the quadratic formula past this point you are no longer factoring just finding roots. I have made a formula to factor a quadratic, not solve it.

Comment: @Stephen. My example was simple. If it doesn't come out nice, you have fractions as well as a radical in your factorization. The method works nonetheless...I am essentially now referring to MArio's answer

Comment: I think I may not be getting my point across and that is on me. The method I have allows a computer to factor an equation without 'thinking.' My method is a formula that factors the equation without contingencies. Also, I am not finding roots I am factoring. (3x^2+8x+2) does not equal (x + (8 (+or-) sqrt(40))/4)

Answer (score 0):

See also "completing the square".
For example, $x^2+6x+8=(x+3)^2-1$,

so $x^2+6x+8=y$ translates to $(x+3)^2=y+1$ or simply $x=\pm \sqrt{y+1}-3$

However, I also encourage you to play around on your own, as that's how you develop your own understanding of these concepts.